# how to create slideshow with imageView?

Tags: android, android-widget

```
 public class AndroidAnim extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
    final ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
    final AnimationDrawable myAnimation1;
    imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadinganim);
    imageView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadinganim);
    myAnimation1 = (AnimationDrawable) imageView1.getBackground();
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myAnimation1.start();
            imageView2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.effect_in));        
        }
    });

  }
  }
```

I am new in android. I need some help. I use this code trying to create slideShow, I want loop images one after another, of course with effect (effect-in.xml in this example). I want to move down imageView1 and after that should move down imageView2, and after that imageView1 and so on. What should I do here, so I get the result, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android ViewFlipper which allows to specify a in and out animation for the different views and it will only show 1 view at a time. You set it to flip automatically.

But if you are looking for a continuous slider of a group of images [this project](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo) might be some reference.